# Insert a line into a PowerPoint using python pptx module

Tags: python, python-pptx

The following lines of codes shows how to draw a line in PowerPoint slides using python. However, the four parameters in inches listed below only takes positive values so could not draw backwards. Is there any other way to draw lines in PowerPoint slides?

```
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
line1 = slide.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.LINE_INVERSE, Inches(6), Inches(6), Inches(1), Inches(2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw lines using the connector object versus the shape object, (Shape requires x,y, height, and width and powerpoint can't deal with negative heights)

From the [docs](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/shp-connector.html?highlight=add_line)

> Lines are a sub-category of auto shape that differ in certain properties and behaviors. In particular, they have a start point and end point in addition to extents (left, top, width, height).
>
> Connectors are based on the  element and have one of a handful of different preset geometry values, such as line. Freeform connectors, despite the name, are not connectors, and are a custom geometry shape based on the p:sp element.
>
> Connectors can be “connected” to an auto shape such that a connected end point remains connected when the auto shape is moved. This relies on a concept of “connection points” on the auto shape. These connections points are preset features of the auto shape, similar to how adjustment points are pre-defined. Connection points are identified by index.

Using the code below allows you to draw a straight line from x = 4 inches to x= 2 inches.

```
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_CONNECTOR
from pptx import Presentation 


# Make sure you have a presentation called test1.pptx in your working directory


prs = Presentation(pptx='test1.pptx')
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[1])
#shapes.add_connector(MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y


line1=slide.shapes.add_connector(MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, Inches(4), Inches(2), Inches(1), Inches(2))

prs.save('test2.pptx')
```

Comment: What about arrows? What do we need to change to insert an arrow connector?

Comment: How can I dotted lines?

Comment: Corroborating this, I created connectors and lines in python-pptx. For lines at least I had to be careful which end was which. Getting it wrong and python-pptx was happy but PowerPoint thought the file corrupt and deleted the lines. I never got connectors to work - with similar PowerPoint "corruption" issues. I would blame PowerPoint for being overly picky - unless the OOXML spec suggests otherwise. Has anyone tried this with eg LibreOffice?